# Java Double Quote

Tags: java

I need to find a way to check for double quotes in a string to I can write the output to an XML document and then open in word. I figured out how to look for a single quote like (') but the double quote is throwing a error in my XML document.

```
     private String checkForDoubleQuote(String l) {
    String newLine = new String();
    char d = '\"';


    for (int index=0;index < l.length();index++) {
        if(l.indexOf(8220)>-1 || l.indexOf(8221)>-1 ||
                 l.indexOf(34)>-1) {
            char c = l.charAt(index);     
             newLine += c;
        } else {
            char c = l.charAt(index);     
            newLine += c;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("new Line --> " + newLine);
    return newLine;
}
```

Here is the XML word output that is causing be trouble: (the two square boxes are x93 and x94 in the XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<w:wordDocument xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml">
<w:body>
<w:p>
<w:r>
<w:rPr>
<w:b/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t></w:t>
<w:t>x93That was close,x94 Lester said between breaths.</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
</w:body>
</w:wordDocument>
```

Comment: Literal character codes `0x93` and `0x94` are Windows-1252 codes for curly open and close quotes, and should not appear in XML declared as UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to strip all the singlequote and doublequote characters out of a string, as well as those silly special quotes that MS Office throws in, here is a method to do it:

```
public static String stripQuote(String l) {
    StringBuffer newLine = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i=0; i<l.length(); i++) {
        char ch = l.charAt(i);
        if (ch==8220 || ch==8221 || ch=='\"' || ch=='\'') {
            //do nothing
        }
        else {
            newLine.append(ch);
        }
    }
    return newLine.toString();
}
```

The code you used in the example constructs many strings over the processing of the line.  This constructs only one.

You also need to worry about anglebracket characters ("<") as well.

However, if instead of stripping them out, you want to encode them properly in XML, you might do this:

```
public static String encodeQuote(String l) {
    StringBuffer newLine = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i=0; i<l.length(); i++) {
        char ch = l.charAt(i);
        if (ch==8220 || ch==8221 || ch=='\"') {
            newLine.appent("&quot;");
        }
        else if (ch=='<') {
            newLine.appent("&lt;");
        }
        else if (ch=='>') {
            newLine.appent("&gt;");
        }
        else if (ch=='\'') {
            newLine.appent("&#39;");
        }
        else {
            newLine.append(ch);
        }
    }
    return newLine.toString();
}
```

Comment: Quotes don't need escaping in XML; only `lt`, `gt` & `amp` need it. (Further: `&quot;` *may* raise an "Undefined entity" if it's not declared in wordml.)

Comment: You are right!  I often convert them anyway so I can use the same encoding for attribute values as for the content.  For XML, &quot; is one of the five standard entities -- should be valid everywhere.

Comment: “Andrew, you’ve got to think of something,” he pleaded. <-- This line of text will throw and error on the single quote but it will work on some of the single quotes. Why would this work sometimes and then not work on other times. It will work on something like don't.  Are single quotes different.

Comment: This is the XML code that is produce                                                             
<w:t>&quot;Andrew, youx93e got to think of something,&quot; he pleaded.</w:t>  The x93 is what is causing the errors.

Comment: that is a single quote from word. I copied the text from a word document to my text file. That throws an ERROR in my XML code. If I retype the single quote then I don't have any ERRORS. Why would this be? and how could I error check for this trouble if I wanted to paste code from a word document and then into a text file.

Comment: If you copy from word to text, you have to worry about the encoding of the text file that the text editor is using.  Your XML header claims this text will be UTF-8 encoded. Is your editor properly encoding in UTF-8?  Most don't.  If editor writes ISO-8859-1, it will have byte sequences which are simply not allowed in UTF-8. If the 'x93' above means a single byte of that value, then that byte is not allowed by itself in UTF-8.  Use a hex editor to verify the actual encoding of the text file.

Comment: Well, I am new to this type of HEX editor. Were would I find a HEX editor. I have notePad++ but I don't think that is the case. When you mean UTF-8 you are talking about the byte sequence in notePad or the XML document (<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>) this I would imagine. Is there any way to just change the encoding in the XML document so that you can write to the single quote to word with out it screaming about an error.

Comment: [HexEdit](http://www.hexedit.com/) won't solve your problem, but it will allow you to see whether there is a problem.   The thing is that in UTF-8, any character value (code point) greater than 127 is encoded by a sequence of 2, 3, or 4 byte values.  All byte values > 127 are always involved in multiple byte sequences, and there are specific orders that are allowed.  You need to get that character properly encoded into a multiple byte sequence by using a text editor that supports UTF-8.